# Under what assumptions on φ is Tco-φ a topology

Tags: calculus, general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing

Fix a set X, and let φ be a property that subsets A of X can have.
Define
Tco-φ = {U ⊆ X : A = ∅, or X \ U has φ } .
Under what assumptions on φ is Tco-φ a topology on X?

What I think:
1. X\X has  φ 
2.$\bigcap_{\alpha \in I}$(X\ $U_\alpha$) has  φ 
3. $\bigcup_{\alpha \in I}$(X\ $U_\alpha$) has  φ 
I'm not sure about this answer at all, any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re on the right track, but what you have isn’t quite right. Notice that the sets with $\varphi$ are simply the closed sets except possibly $X$ itself. Thus, $\{X\}\cup\{C\subseteq X:C\text{ has }\varphi\}$ is the collection of closed sets of some topology. This means that the property $\varphi$ must be such that:

- $\varnothing$ has $\varphi$ (so that $X$ is open);
- if $\mathscr{C}$ is *any* family of sets that each have $\varphi$, then $\bigcap\mathscr{C}$ has $\varphi$ (so that $\mathscr{T}_{\text{co-}\varphi}$ is closed under taking arbitrary unions; and
- if $\mathscr{F}$ is a *finite* family of sets that each have $\varphi$, then $\bigcup\mathscr{F}$ has $\varphi$ (so that $\mathscr{T}_{\text{co-}\varphi}$ is closed under taking finite intersections).

The point that you missed is that your third condition should be only for finite unions, i.e., for the case in which the index set $I$ is finite.